# What is the linguistic cause of the formation of "competete" a wrong variant of "compete"?

Tags: english, phonetics, morphology, sociolinguistics, stress

Compete**te** a variant of *Compete* used in colloquial speech, but is written with the same spelling as the latter, has come into use (at the least) in Indian English variants if in no other English variants.

The question here is how could it have been formed? I had a few ideas of my own:

1) It is maybe the result of *-tion* deletion which generally adds a *t* sound in return, thus adding an extra *t* sound after *compete*.

2) It is maybe the pronunciation /kum-**pe**-ti-shun/ and not /**kom**-puh-ti-shun/ which requires the extra *t* sound syllable to maintain the pronunciation stress on *pe* - /kum-**pe**-teet/ and not /**kum**-peet/

Edit: this is unlike association -> associate and connotation -> connotate

Comment: In Indian English I've usually heard /kum(p)-**ti**-shun/, so I don't know if that is the whole reason. Btw remember that stress in Indian English corresponds with lower intonation.

Comment: @aryaman the variant you are talking about exists in places around U.P. belt (if you know what I am talking about) , I did not intentionally compare that, because it would have added confusion. About lower intonation I'll have to learn more.

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be common in more rural/uneducated accent. I am a Dilliwala, so I am familiar with UP speech.

Comment: @aryaman I was exactly second guessing that ;)

Comment: @Aryaman: "... remember that stress in Indian English corresponds with lower intonation." -- Can you support your claim with any references, facts, data, etc.?

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed Pickering, Lucy, and Caroline Wiltshire. "Pitch accent in Indian‐English teaching discourse." *World Englishes* 19.2 (2000): 173-183.

Answer (score 3):

It's called analogy, and besides *competition* there is also *competitor* (already with two t's) suggesting the form *to competete*.

Looking at the Latin original forms (competere, competo, competivi, competitum) the creation of the form *to compete* looks irregular, it should be something like *to competite* using the most prevalent borrowing pattern of modern English.

Comment: 1) are you suggesting that Indian English is not the only langugae to have this? 2) Is this **the** answer?, i.e. is this green-tick-mark-able or is there multiple answers / thoughts one could give?

Comment: 1) I have no data, but I'd expect other varieties of English to show this as well. 2) You can wait for some days for more answers to appear here and than chose where to put the green tick.

Comment: The point is that adult 2nd language learners may hear derivations first (competitive, etc.) and use analogy to construct an erroneous root.